# Are bats described as birds?

Tags: word-study, leviticus

Leviticus 11:13,19 reads:

> And these you shall detest among the birds . . . the eagle, the bearded vulture, the black vulture . . . and the bat. (ESV translation)

Does the bible describe bats as being a bird?

Modern science indicates that taxonomically speaking, bats aren't birds, but mammals.

Comment: The Hebrew word for fowl in these verses is **עוֹף**, which means "wing" (winged creatures). Please click [**here**](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H5775&t=NASB).

Comment: Be aware also that there is a kind of "bananas are berries" approach to scientific terminology that mistakes the map for the territory. "Bats" are not "birds", but this is because we choose to define the category "bird" in a certain way, and the category "bat" in a certain way. We didn't "discover that bats aren't birds" since Lev. was written, rather we changed the meaning of "bird". The sentence "bats are birds" does *not* necessarily assert incorrectly that bats have feathers, if the person stating it intentionally means a different thing by the category "bird" than you do.

Comment: I just got a notification that this has received 2500 views. In hindsight, a prohibition against eating bats seems like a *really* good prohibition.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Hebrew word was used for winged creatures that weren't insects. Applying 'modern science' to an ancient culture's classifications of the world is anachronistic.

The *Tyndale Bible Dictionary* reads:

> Modern scientists classify organisms on the basis of internal and external structure, but the biblical writers generally classified organisms according to habitat.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Editors: Walter A. Elwell, Philip Wesley Comfort, *Tyndale Bible Dictionary*, p.215.

Comment: *Applying 'modern science' to an ancient culture's classifications of the world is anachronistic.* -- And a warning that it can be dangerous to take ancient descriptions literally.

Comment: _And a warning that it can be dangerous to take ancient descriptions literally_ - Not applicable: The **literal** translation of **עוף**  is flying/winged creature, not the modern taxonomic "bird".

Comment: @SteveJessop - agreed, absolutely. Translation of the ancient Hebrew is very tricky business and most modern translations are distillations of other translations, etc and can be rife with errors, both unintentional and intentional (to promote a particular theology) - whatever your religious persuasion, to understand the Hebrew correctly one must go to the original sources.

Comment: 9 UV's as I type! This has answer to have one of the highest UV-to-keystroke+labour ratios on BH.SE. ;) (P.s. My +1 is in there!)

Comment: There's no such scientific category as "domestic animals" either. Doesn't mean it isn't a *useful* category for non-scientific purposes.

Comment: @Davïd It is also, weirdly/sadly, my highest voted answer.

Comment: @Davïd and Mark, this question was spawned by some controversial comments included in an [answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20838/933) to a related question on a much higher traffic SE site. The thread has been cleaned up but the link to this remains and the question hit the SE network wide hot-list spilling some traffic over here: hence the unusual voting pattern.

Answer (score 15):

*All citations are from the orignal Hebrew and Aramaic, not translations*

In modern Hebrew, **עטלף**, the word to which I believe you are referring, indeed means **bat**. But [**Targum Yonason**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Pseudo-Jonathan) translates that  word as **טרפידא** in Aramaic, which, based on the roots, (to capture prey by chasing it down and ripping it apart)  leans more towards a sort of owl or other bird of prey that pounces on its prey with its talons, whereas bats, especially those found in the Old World, do not acquire their food in such manner:

> [**Bats are the second largest order of
>   mammals**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat) (after the rodents),
>   representing about 20% of all classified mammal species worldwide,
>   with about 1,240 bat species divided into two suborders: the less
>   specialized and largely fruit-eating megabats, or flying foxes, and
>   the highly specialized and echolocating microbats.[5] About 70% of bat
>   species are insectivores. Most of the rest are frugivores, or fruit
>   eaters. A few species, such as the fish-eating bat, feed from animals
>   other than insects, with the vampire bats being hematophagous, or
>   feeding on blood.

[**Abraham ibn Ezra**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) explains on **עטלף** : "A small **עוף** (flying creature) that flies at night" - perhaps a bat, but could just as well mean a type of owl or other nocturnal bird of prey. [**RAMBAN (Nahmanides)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahmanides) on those verses explains that the underlying reason for the prohibition is that the species mentioned are birds of prey.  (Clearly the other species mentioned in that verse are **feathered birds**.) Again, consistent with Targum Yonason, that would eliminate the bat, which is not a predator. except for the few species mentioned above, not found in the RAMBAN's proximity.

If the translation is indeed **bat**, then @MarkEdward's answer is obviously the correct one: Biblical Hebrew is not the language of modern taxonomy. However, that translation is arguably incorrect, (nor is modern, spoken Hebrew a reliable reference for interpreting biblical verses) and if we translate differently - **owl** - such as suggested, your question falls aside.

(That is not to say the bat is a kosher animal. As a rodent, it lacks the required characteristics - cloven hooves, chews its cud.)